# 500 Server error when try to get content from Google Images using Web Speech API

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to dynamically collect some free images from Google using the Web Speech API.

Here's the logic:

1. I capture the search keyword with the Web Speech API in JS.
2. I send it to the server (PHP) using an ajax call
3. Then I process the keyword and send back the results to JS.

Everything works fine if the keyword is just a single word like: Barack, but if I use Barack Obama there is a 500 Server Error and the ajax call fails.

JavaScript

```
$keyword = 'Barack Obama'; //the $Keyword is created from the result of the Web Speech API, but to make this clearer I just created it manually bc the problem still there anyway.
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: '../php/myfunctions.php',
        data: {$keyword:$keyword},
        dataType:"json",
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log('yeah');
    })
    .fail(function(responseText) {
        console.warn('error: ',responseText);
    });
```

PHP

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/library/simple_html_dom.php');
$keyword = $_POST['$keyword'];
$keyword = 'Barack Obama'; //IF I manually create the $keyword all is fine but It's not the idea so this line is just to debug this issue.
$keyword = strtolower($keyword); //I tried with lowercases (barack obama).
$keyword = rawurlencode($keyword); //Then I tried a encoding workaround (barack%20obama).
$keyword = str_replace(' ','',$keyword); //Then I tried without white spaces(barackobama).
$url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' . $keyword . '&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=sur:fc&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQgMn87ajaAhUOtlkKHdgZB_8QpwUIHg&biw=1745&bih=872&dpr=1.1'; 
$html = file_get_html($url);
//From here I handle this data and I send it back in a json to JS
echo $url //if I echo the $url these are the outputs:

https://www.google.com/search?q=barack obama&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=sur:fc&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQgMn87ajaAhUOtlkKHdgZB_8QpwUIHg&biw=1745&bih=872&dpr=1.1 

https://www.google.com/search?q=barack%20obama&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=sur:fc&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQgMn87ajaAhUOtlkKHdgZB_8QpwUIHg&biw=1745&bih=872&dpr=1.1 

https://www.google.com/search?q=barackobama&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=sur:fc&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQgMn87ajaAhUOtlkKHdgZB_8QpwUIHg&biw=1745&bih=872&dpr=1.1
```

If I copy&paste these 3 URLs in the browser manually there is no problem and all the images appear, but if the $keyword created in JS has 2 words like New York there is a 500 error.

What could be the problem? Greetings.

Comment: In ajax settings - change `{$keyword:$keyword}` - to - `{keyword:'$keyword'}`

Comment: I don't think you need - dataType:"json", - unless you're expecting a json response. Remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
data: {$keyword: $keyword}
```

use

```
data: {keyword: encodeURIComponent($keyword)}
```

And drop the `dataType: 'json'` since you are definitely not echoing json there.

Comment: This works perfectly. I do require json bc I didn't put in the code all the answer to JS which is json data from PHP. Thank you for your time. Greetings.